# Error when building a game with playscape SDK 1.11

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

I am integrating Playscape 1.11 SDK to my game in unity. When running the build for android I am getting after sometime the following error:
an error occured while applying post-build logic: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter Name: path1

I attached [an image of the error](https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_9050/0l5zM4O3KJA5lTApzmScwVF2cnggwJ/%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BE%25D1%2587%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B9%2B%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%2B2015-07-14%2B18.31.52.png?Expires=1437563110&Signature=AoIF1xxMlnv8n~9aRcMgdJXj~E3GJ~fOZjekUnGV4vMdTwfshzbqzbItfESf8ISbL70DXeh9PCMwb0XKX45cL~bwbW9r414XHC3FXR87NxJzbEw~3pOeC4FgClMA2~rX-Vjs7eLD~id~75n983~s32mzLK63wUICI~eI21637DEbuVdmPOrcsCl05oxwTjRH~MZAECMg9OKJeMDh9UopoWmbWkCV8tw3lERf~EA1LwSx1nZvfi2gJw0iRt3BOKjpsQ5R7ExvL6a0tdEk1trAUUnbWD8WtwoCxJdNAF4QFFsW8uvonlRZXjAJYmid1AYAflvhzsT-OBW3Br9xC9LUww__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivan, You are missing ANDROID_HOME env. variable. Please configure it correctly. This should solve your issue.